# iPad UIWebView Action Toolbar Display

Tags: objective-c, pdf, ipad, uiwebview, toolbar

I have a pdf open in a UIWebView and I would like to allow the option to open it in Pages. That is, I would like the action toolbar to become displayed when the user taps on the UIWebView (just like in Safari for iPad). How do you enable this capability in UIWebView, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at using the Quick Look framework.  It automatically will add in the toolbar across the top of the page and insert buttons to open the PDF in any other application installed on the iPad which is capable of displaying it.  It will also add in a Print button.